# How to consume Alfresco Enterprise REST API in .NET?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am having very hard time finding some tutorial that can help me jump-start my development work with Alfresco.

I have 0 experience with Alfresco and doing some exploration.

I want to write a web app or console app in C# .NET that can do these:
 - Authenticate with the Repository
 - Create a folder
 - Retrieve the content of the folder
 - Persist a document
 - Retrieve a document
 - Few others...

I spent several hours to locate useful tutorial but haven't found any.

I also posted a question on Alfresco forum but 0 response.

I just need the steps to get started...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the DotCMIS API from Apache Chemistry

See
https://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/getting-started-with-dotcmis.html

Using DotCMIS, you can point to any CMIS compliant server.

Comment: We will be using the REST API not the CMIS. Where do I find what dlls and other settings/config I need to do? Like in SharePoint, I know the DLLs that I need to add as reference before I am able to consume SharePoint API.

Comment: Apache Chemistry DotCMIS is a CMIS client library for .NET. So it is a layer above REST. So if you were to use it/download it, you would reference DotCMIS.dll